# pip not getting current version

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have a Django app published on github, which I also mirror on PyPi to make installation easy. It's been at version 1.3 for a year, but 12 hours ago I bumped it to a new version 1.4 on PyPi. I hid version 1.3 on PyPi and made sure all references are to the new version. But

`pip install my-package`

still pulls down  version 1.3. And specifying the version:

`pip install my-package==1.4`

returns

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package==1.4 (from versions: 1.3)`

Various posts suggest removing pip's tmp directory, but I can't find one (either in `/tmp` or in `~/.pip`. And I can't find any mention of caching delays at PyPi.

Am I missing something?

Ideally what I'd love to do would be to just have the PyPi entry point back to github, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that there is no package available, which matches the version string. This refers to the version string of your Python package on PyPI.

Make sure that the version string you provide in your `setup.py` file of your project matches the version you're releasing.

Then you run `python setup.py sdist upload` in your project folder to create the source distribution archive and upload it to PyPI. -- You may have to delete your current, erroneous package with the "1.4" version string from PyPI beforehand.

Comment: Ah - I had looked everywhere for the version string but in the __init__.py. Makes perfect sense. Thanks so much!